# Ignore built-in FxCop rules for some specific cases. Custom FxCop rules?

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

I am developing some async code using Web Api, and I get a lot of FxCop errors that I would like to suppress. For example the following code in my controller would trigger these errors:

1. UsePropertiesWhereAppropriate
2. MarkMembersAsStatic
3. DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures

> ```
> public Task<HttpResponseMessage<IEnumerable<Foo>>> GetAsync()
> {
> }
> ```

I do not want to suppress these rules for the whole assembly, so it seems like the only way to suppress the errors in code is to add a `SuppressMessage` attribute for each violated rule on each method. Is there a better way to suppress the errors? I am thinking of custom FxCop rules... Is it possible to create a rule like "Ignore `DoNotNestGenericTypesInMemberSignatures` for `Task<T>`" or "Ignore these rules for any type inheriting from Bar class"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to get any of the Microsoft-provided rules to conditionally ignore certain types or members like this.  You have three basic choices:

1. Suppress each violation individually,
2. Disable the rules entirely for the assemblies containing the "special" types, or
3. Disable the Microsoft-provided rules, but provide alternate custom rules that are able to ignore your types.

Personally, I would opt for #1, but ymmv...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closest answer for this is [Custom Rule in FxCop to only apply to methods called by particular type's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426114/custom-rule-in-fxcop-to-only-apply-to-methods-called-by-particular-types-method) ? Hopefully, that works for you, otherwise I would say the answer is no

Comment: This is what the "close" link is for, to close as a duplicate of another question. If you aren't sure, leave a comment, not an answer.